# Why TEXTJOIN function in excel doesn't work correctly?

Tags: excel

I have two tables, first table contains Group name in column A, task for this group in column B and comments for each task in column C.

Now i have to get all these comments for each task to show up in one cell for appropriate group in second table. I used TEXTJOIN function:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",  ";TRUE;IF(A2:A12=E2;C2:C12;""))
```

However, it joined all comments into first cell all for first group. What is wrong in my function?

[image: excel example])

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter?

Comment: No, i did not. Thanks, i forgot that i should use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when using an array formula. :)

Comment: Now if i have a blank cell in A2:A12, i get a 0, How to stop returning 0 if formula is blank?